# Resize linux parition without reinstalling

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

Here's what my partition table looks like. How can I expand the 20 GB / partition without having to reinstall everything? I'd like it to be, say, 50 GB.

[image: GParted on Ubuntu 14.04]

Comment: Where is the extra 30gb going to come from? You will need to shrink an existing partition and move the partitions so that the free space exists with the partition you need to grow... pretty sure

Comment: @Matt Yes, that's what I meant. The point is, the / partition is sandwiched, as I see it, in a very bad place.

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to move the other partitions out of the way. DONT FORGET TO BACKUP FIRST

Comment: <<goosebumps>> Will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reduce sda3 by 30 GB, extend sda4 by 30 GB, move sda5 & sda6 to the beginning of sda4, extend sda7 to 50 GB,  Backup everything first in case something goes wrong

Comment: Interesting idea. I've done some partitioning before but never moved a partition. Let's see how it goes this time. :|

Comment: Did it and nothing went wrong. Thank you! ^.^

Answer (score 1):

If done carefully, you can use [gparted](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) to resize your partitions safely.

You should boot to a live image since you can't resize mounted partitions, and make sure you have a valid back up of your data!!

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Feeling happy! :D